# Наследник от UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

Как создать класс-наследник от UITableView и описать в нем delegate и dataSource, для того, чтобы не вызывать эти функции в контроллере?

Comment: Не поделитесь зачем?

Comment: @VAndrJ ну очевидно же: чтоб весь код работы таблицы запихать в сам класс таблицы и никогда его не видеть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю как наследовать таблицу вы представляете (и не забыть в сабклассе указать, что он поддерживает dataSource и delegate протоколы)

```
class MyTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

дальше, вам надо в сабклассе переписать все иниты (коих там три: init, init(frame, style), init(coder) ), и в каждом назначить себя делегатом и датасурсом примерно так:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}
```

ну и дальше там же пишете все методы протоколов, которые вам нужны.

Comment: Все сделал, теперь ругается на несоответствие протоколу UITableViewDataSource, хотя методы numberOfSections, numberOfRows и cellForRaw объявлены.. http://s02.radikal.ru/i175/1609/d3/a39deb3f9df0.png

Comment: У Вас не верно задана функция `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - формат такой:   `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Большое спасибо, ошибка ушла. Только теперь вылетает на инициализации convenience init(). Не подскажете, как исправить?